# betting in fair game over infinite horizon, is it possible to win?

Tags: probability, expected-value, martingales, random-walk, gambling

If a gambler were to play in a fair game, lets say he wins/loses 1 dollar with equal probability in each step. Let $X_i$ denote the amount of money he has after $i$ steps. And he plays until he either runs out of money or decides to stop, in which case he cashes in what he currently has. Let us denote this stopping time as $T$. Then starting with $n$ dollars, if $E(T)<\infty$ using optional stopping theorem one can show that $E(X_T)=n$. However this is no longer applicable if $E(T)=\infty$. Could there potentially be a strategy for the gambler such that $E(T)=\infty$ and $E(X_T)>n$?

Comment: In the fair game you described, the probability to be in plus at some point is $1$ , nevertheless the expected number of games necessary to be in a plus is $\infty$. Even if you had an edge, there would be a positive probability that you would run out of money before you can stop with a plus.

Comment: Yes, but I care about the expected win, not if it is possible to ensure a win. ofc with positive probability gambler will never have more then n dollars. Intuitively it should not be possible to have expected win more then $n$, but I am interested in concrete proofs...

Comment: It is possible to have $E(T)=\infty$ and $E(X_T)<n$, for example by deciding to stop only when the amount of money held is $k$ for some $k<n$

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But the case I am interested in is specifically for $E(T)=\infty$ and $E(X_T)>n$.

Comment: Are you still assuming $X_i \ge 0$ for all $i$, or is the gambler allowed to go into debt in this setup?

Comment: Just flip the sign in Henry's argument -- but make sure to give the gambler an unlimited gambling debt allowance....

Comment: If we allow debt then yes, it becomes easy as well. I assume $X_i\geq 0$, that is no debt allowed. The moment $X_i=0$ the game ends and his gain is $0$.

Comment: Are you interested in the specific case where each wager is a fair $\$1$ bet, or are you open to a more general betting scheme?

Comment: I am mainly interested in the general case where the bets are fair (expected win in each step is $0$) and maximum gain/loss per bet is bounded. But I welcome even results withouth bounded gain/loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $T < \infty$ a.s., there is no way for $\mathbb{E}[X_T] > n$ if we enforce the no debt condition $X_m \ge 0$ for all $m$.

For any $m$ we have $\mathbb{E}[X_{T \wedge m}] = n$ by the optional stopping theorem (since $T \wedge m$ is a stopping time with finite expectation), and since $T < \infty$ a.s., $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} X_{T \wedge m} = X_T$ a.s.  Since $X_{T \wedge m} \ge 0$ for all $m$, by Fatou's lemma we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_T] = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}X_{T \wedge m}] \le \liminf_{m \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_{T \wedge m}] \le n.
\end{align*}

If we allow $\mathbb{P}(T = \infty) > 0$, it's unclear how to define $X_T$ on the event $\{T = \infty\}$.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.